# selenium python click link open in other window, need same

Tags: python, selenium

```
myLink = myDriver.find_element_by_xpath ('....')
myLink.click()
bmyLink = WebDriverWait(myDriver, 10).until(ExConditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '.....')))
```

I use `selenium` with `Firefox` driver `Python` 3.5. I noted that after `click()` another `Firefox` window is opened, so second search for link is done in first window I guess, not where I wanted it to be (on new opened by click page). How to make it work - open new page with `click()` in same window? or else?

Comment: Provide `HTML` for target element

Comment: see this http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#moving-between-windows-and-frames

Answer (score 2):

If after first `click()`.. open a new window, you need to switch that new window first then go to find the link as below :-

```
myLink = myDriver.find_element_by_xpath ('....')
myLink.click()

currentWindow = myDriver.current_window_handle 
#store current window for backup to switch back

for handle in myDriver.window_handles:
    if handle != currentWindow:
        myDriver.switch_to_window(handle)

#now you can do your stuff in new window
bmyLink = WebDriverWait(myDriver, 10).until(ExConditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '.....')))
----

#now close the new window after doing all stuff
myDriver.close()

#after doing all stuff it new window need to switch back on main window
myDriver.switch_to_window(currentWindow)
```

Hope it will help you...:)

Comment: Thank you. Can I close new extra window? Here (http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#moving-between-windows-and-frames) it says only about closing browser as whole. When I have many newly opened windows, your method cannot identify one which was opened last, I suppose.

Comment: @AlexeiMartianov you can close new window by using `myDriver.close` before switch back to main window.

Comment: It's not closing windows, new windows opened on click() stay open after `myDriver.close
   myDriver.switch_to.window(currentWindow)`.

Comment: Small error mine editor do not alert of - `myDriver.close()`, not just `close`. `switch_to.window` same as `switch_to_window`? seemed both working