# Force download file in a Django Web App on mobile browsers

Tags: python, django, download, response

I have a FileField with a movie, I'm trying to have the user on a mobile platform (chrome/safari) be able to click a download button and it download it. Currently it opens in a new window no matter what I do.

My View

```
def download(request):
    file_path = 'movie.mp4'
    if os.path.exists(file_path):
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as fh:
            response = HttpResponse(fh.read(), content_type="video/mp4")
            response['Content-Disposition: attachment'] = 'inline; filename=' + os.path.basename(file_path)
            return response
    raise Http404
```

file path is hard coded for testing purposes atm.

Everything I read tells me that it's impossible because safari and other mobile browsers view opening a better experience than downloading. I've tried changing mime types and other things.

Answer (score 0):

Your `content-disposition` must contain`attachment` to allow the user to download it, it should be something like this:

```
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=' + os.path.basename(file_path) + '.mp4'
```

Comment: I changed it to this and still opens it in a window on mobile browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't  know a lot about python but I saw that you have only one reaction so I have done my bit of research and this is what I found. 
[Click link open in other window need same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38239869/selenium-python-click-link-open-in-other-window-need-same)
I know it's not a download but a download is always a way of using a link.
Maybe you are able to combine those codes and make it work.

note that download links are always opened in a new window but automatically close.

I hope you will be able to make some progress

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think this helps me :/

Comment: Ah, too bad. Found out anything yet?

Comment: Nothing... It sucks. I've switched to trying to develop a KiK bot to do what I need it to do (send content to a kik user) instead hoping someone figures something out. There are a lot of other questions similar to this one as well.